# Program Crashing and some questions about arithmetic operations in coding

Tags: c

Hi stackoverflow community! I'm having some problems with my code. I'm currently a student so basically I'm a beginner. Using Euclidean Algorithm, the code shown below should divide and divide two numbers until the quotient reach 0 but it just stops at the last dividing process just before the quotient turns 0. I don't know if the program crashes because of this. Hoping for a beginner-friendly reply from you guys. Thanks! (sorry if there's already an existing question like this)

Here's the code:

```
int quotient,quotient2,remainder,remainder2,x,y;

int foo()
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    if(y >= x){
        quotient2 = y / x;
        remainder2 = y % x;
        printf("%d = %d(%d) + %d\n", y,x,quotient2,remainder2);

        if(quotient2 != 0){
            do{
                y = x;
                x = remainder2;
                quotient2 = y / x;
                remainder2 = y % x; 
                printf("%d = %d(%d) + %d\n", y,x,quotient2,remainder2); 
            } while(quotient2 != 0);    
        }
    } else if(x > y){
        quotient = x / y;
        remainder = x % y;
        printf("%d = %d(%d) + %d\n", x,y,quotient,remainder);

        if(quotient != 0){
            do{
                x = y;
                y = remainder;
                quotient = x / y;
                remainder = x % y;
                printf("%d = %d(%d) + %d\n", x,y,quotient,remainder);
            } while(quotient != 0);
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages -- pick one.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: It probably crashes because in your `do...while` loop, if the result of the `remainder = x % y;` is 0 then you have a division by zero by the next iteration.

Comment: Before you do any division, you should check if your denominator is 0.  You didn't do any of these checks.  Better yet, why not simply print out the values of x, y, etc. *before* you did the division, and not just after?

Comment: More explicitly, with computers, integer dividing by zero will cause an exception (crash for you).  You need to check before the divide occurs.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan How do i check and avoid the error when dividing by 0? Sorry for a noob question

Comment: @Wimmel I tried to but the program just crashed

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Print out the values of the variables before the division? Can't fully understand it i'm sorry

Comment: @aspiringprogrammer -- `if (y == 0) { do_not_do_division } else { do_division }`

Comment: @bkVnet thank you for pointing out the problem. I dont know how to fix it but i need to have a formula that displays the quotient as 0

Comment: @aspiringprogrammer Instead of guessing why it crashes, print out the values that you're going to use in the division before you divide.  Then you would have seen that your `y` is 0, thus the division would not have worked.  But in general, are you learning how to debug programs?  What I suggested is the basics in debugging, and that is printing out values to see what they are so that you can diagnose your own issues with the program, even before asking for help.  Then there is a tool called a debugger that automates this and allows you to step through your program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you sir. But i need to make the quotient 0. I can't possibly do that using these codes

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't know yet on how to debug programs but i tried using the debugger tool in the IDE. Thank you for your help sir and please be patient with me

Comment: Advice 1: if x > y, just swap them and get rid of all the repeated code.  It will make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your "Euclidean algorithm" is computing the GCD of two numbers, here is one way to do it. Note it does not divide by 0, it stops when the divisor would be 0.

So the point is, rather than guard against dividing by 0, that's the iteration's end condition anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned gcd(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    unsigned z;
    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    while ((z = y % x) != 0) {
        y = x;
        x = z;
    }
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("20 ~ 20 : %u\n", gcd(20, 20));
    printf("20 ~ 0  : %u\n", gcd(20,  0));
    printf(" 0 ~ 20 : %u\n", gcd( 0, 20));
    printf("20 ~ 16 : %u\n", gcd(20, 16));
    printf("16 ~ 20 : %u\n", gcd(16, 20));
    printf("20 ~ 15 : %u\n", gcd(20, 15));
    printf("15 ~ 20 : %u\n", gcd(15, 20));
    printf(" 1 ~  2 : %u\n", gcd( 1,  2));
    printf(" 2 ~  1 : %u\n", gcd( 2,  1));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
20 ~ 20 : 20
20 ~ 0  : 0
 0 ~ 20 : 0
20 ~ 16 : 4
16 ~ 20 : 4
20 ~ 15 : 5
15 ~ 20 : 5
 1 ~  2 : 1
 2 ~  1 : 1
```

Note there is no need to swap the arguments. The algorithm works no matter which way round they are.

Comment: For shame - variable assignments in conditional checks (while)? Lol.  I'd have added some parenthesis to get rid of the warnings it would generate.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan amended viz your suggestion, but I would call my first post "idiomatic". I rather not be explicit with boolean tests and I never use `true` and `false`. No warnings.

Comment: Of course, if he turns this in as homework as-is, he'll have quite a bit of explaining to do...

Comment: `while ((z = y % x))` doesn't rise any warning too (at least in my version of gcc), If you don't like to be explicit with boolean tests.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you sir. I'm getting the point of just using modulo to get what i want. I just can't put and make the code run together with the code i made right now its so confusing

Comment: "Note it does not divide by 0," --> Corner case: `GCD(0,y)` and `GCD(x,0)` do a `%0`  which is also UB.

Comment: When `x` or `y` are zero, may want to see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27719/what-is-gcd0-a-where-a-is-a-positive-integer.  Perhaps `if (x == 0 || y == 0) { return 0; }` --> `if (x == 0) { return y;  }`?

Comment: @chux hmmm... suppose both are 0? It seems a bit elusive, as in the GIGO principle? Is the aim to prevent div 0, or to protect programmer from himself? But agreed, 0 cannot be a common (or any) divisor.

Comment: `0` is unusual input, yet little need for code to go UB with such input, even with `gcd(0,0)` as there is a reasonable result.  IMO, good code handles corner cases like this - documenting its behavior if there is some input combination that would cause UB. UV for a good demo of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that with `x = remainder2;`, `x` could take on the value of `0`.  Then the next `quotient2 = y / x; remainder2 = y % x;` both perform operations (divide by 0 and remainder 0) which are both undefined behavior.  The program crash is certainly due to this.

```
if(y >= x){
    quotient2 = y / x;
    remainder2 = y % x;
    printf("%d = %d(%d) + %d\n", y,x,quotient2,remainder2);

    if(quotient2 != 0){
        do{
            y = x;
            x = remainder2;
            quotient2 = y / x;
            remainder2 = y % x; 
            printf("%d = %d(%d) + %d\n", y,x,quotient2,remainder2); 
        } while(quotient2 != 0);    
    }
```

---

As code is swapping the roles of `x,y` with each operation, code could simplify to:  (Also see [What is gcd(0,a)gcd(0,a), where a is a positive integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27719/what-is-gcd0-a-where-a-is-a-positive-integer)

```
unsigned gcd(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  while (b) {
    a %= b;
    if (a == 0) return b;
    b %= a;
  }
  return a;
}
```