# What is the fastest way to list the elements of the unit group of a given size?

Tags: c, performance, math, number-theory

There are several fast algorithms to calculate prime numbers up to a given number n. But, what is the fastest implementation to list all the numbers r relatively prime to some number n in C? That is, find all the elements of the multiplicative group with n elements as efficiently as possible in C. In particular, I am interested in the case where n is a primorial.

The n primorial is like the factorial except only prime numbers are multiplied together and all other numbers are ignored. So, for example 12 primorial would be 12#=11*7*5*3*2.

My current implementation is very naive. I hard code the first 3 groups as arrays and use those to create the larger ones. Is there something faster?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, fgets */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atoi */
#include <math.h>


int IsPrime(unsigned int number) 
{
    if (number <= 1) return 0; // zero and one are not prime

    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int max=sqrt(number)+.5;

    for (i = 2; i<= max; i++) 
    {
        if (number % i == 0) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

unsigned long long primorial( int Primes[], int size)
{
    unsigned long long answer = 1;

    for (int k = 0;k < size;k++)
    {
        answer *= Primes[k];
    }

    return answer;
}

unsigned long long EulerPhi(int Primes[], int size)
{
    unsigned long long answer = 1;

    for (int k = 0;k < size;k++)
    {
        answer *= Primes[k]-1;
    }

    return answer;
}


int gcd( unsigned long long a,  unsigned long long b)
{
    while (b != 0)
    {
        a %= b;
        a ^= b;
        b ^= a;
        a ^= b;
    }


    //Return whethere a is relatively prime to b
    if (a > 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void gen( unsigned long long *Gx, unsigned int primor, int *G3)
{
    //Get the magic numbers
    register int Blocks = 30;    //5 primorial=30.
    unsigned long long indexTracker = 0;

    //Find  elements using G3
    for (unsigned long long offset = 0; offset < primor; offset+=Blocks)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8;j++)    //The 8 comes from EulerPhi(2*3*5=30)
        {
            if (gcd(offset + G3[j], primor))
            {
                Gx[indexTracker] = offset + G3[j];
                indexTracker++;
            }
        }
    }


}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Hardcoded values
    int G1[] = {1};
    int G2[] = {1,5};
    int G3[] = {1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29};

    //Lazy input checking. The world might come to an end 
    //when unexpected parameters given. Its okey, we will live.
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("Nothing done.");
        return 0;
    }

    //Convert argument to integer
    unsigned int N = atoi(argv[1]);

    //Known values
    if (N <= 2 ) 
    {
        printf("{1}");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (N<=4)
    {
        printf("{1,5}");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (N <=6)
    {
        printf("{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}");
        return 0;
    }

    //Hardcoded for simplicity, also this primorial is ginarmous as it is. 
    int Primes[50] = {0};
    int counter = 0;

    //Find all primes less than N.
    for (int a = 2; a <= N; a++)
    {
        if (IsPrime(a))
        {
            Primes[counter] = a;
            printf("\n  Prime: : %i \n", a);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    //Get the group size
    unsigned long long MAXELEMENT = primorial(Primes, counter);
    unsigned long long Gsize = EulerPhi(Primes, counter);

    printf("\n  GSize: %llu \n", Gsize);
    printf("\n  GSize: %llu \n", Gsize);

    //Create the list to hold the values
    unsigned long long  *GROUP = (unsigned long long *) calloc(Gsize, sizeof(unsigned long long));

    //Populate the list
    gen( GROUP, MAXELEMENT, G3);

    //Print values
    printf("{");
    for (unsigned long long k = 0; k < Gsize;k++)
    {
        printf("%llu,", GROUP[k]);
    }
    printf("}");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fastest way would probably involve using a fast algorithm to completely factor the given number so as to list the numbers which are *not* relatively prime (hence get the complementary set of the numbers which are relatively prime). A related idea (that will also involve factoring) is to exploit the multiplicative nature of Euler's phi function. Write n as a*b with gcd(a,b) = 1, recursively find numbers x,y relatively prime to a,b then use the Chinese remainder theorem to get the numbers relatively prime to n.

Comment: For the case of interest the complete factorization is already known for every input. The first option would not be more efficient than my current implementation. I skip reasonable chunks of numbers, that is I do not even consider them, so visiting every integer at least once to make a determination is out of the question. The second suggestion looks fancy, maybe promising. I will think about it.

Comment: To begin with, you check every number in the range for primality including the even numbers, when the only even prime is 2. So you can halve the execution time of that section at a stroke. For another thing, `IsPrime` tests every possible divisor (up to the square root), when you only need to test divisibilty with the primes you already established (but didn't keep an array of). Do that and you'll get another approx 10-fold speed improvement. And that's before exploring the rest of the code.

Comment: Point well made. I will test it later today.

Comment: Upon careful scrutiny it will not give much gains. Everything outside the "gen()" function is negligible. I spend  little time outside that function(<2% for N=>23), so optimizing them is kind of pointless at this point(it might not be later). The bottle neck is gcd inside the gen function(>90% time).

Comment: Your GCD function would be more efficient `inline` and also does one operation more than is needed in each iteration. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145327/program-crashing-and-some-questions-about-arithmetic-operations-in-coding/37145812#37145812)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a faster prime number check, here is one that is reasonably fast and eliminates all calls to computationally intensive functions (e.g. `sqrt`, etc..)

```
int isprime (int v)
{
    int i;

    if (v < 0) v = -v;                          /* insure v non-negative */
    if (v < 2 || !((unsigned)v & 1))    /* 0, 1 + even > 2 are not prime */
        return 0;

    for (i = 2; i * i <= v; i++)
        if (v % i == 0)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

(**note:** You can adjust the `type` as required if you are looking for numbers above the standard `int` range.)

Give it a try and let me know how it compares to the once you are currently using.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more efficient as `for (i = 3; i * i <= v; i += 2)` and detecting the special case `2` first? That would double the execution speed.

Comment: My code calls sqrt once. Your code multiplies by i for every iteration of the loop. One expensive call is cheaper than many cheap calls.