# time-saving way to check whether numbers in an array have common factor?

Tags: c, arrays, greatest-common-divisor

The aim of this assignment is to find the number of pairs can be formed by every two number in an array. The condition is that these two number can not have common factors.

I have tried using loop comparing number by number in an array with a loop of factor starts from 2. This code works but it exceeds the time limit for 2 out of 10 cases on codecrunch.

```
double estimate_PI(int list[], int size) {
  int i, pair;
  pair = size * (size - 1) / 2; //total number of pairs can be formed

  int count = pair;
  int j, l;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {        //check the first number in the array
    for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) { //check compare the first number of the rest 
      // of the numbers in the array 
      for (l = 2; l < list[j]; l++) {           //check for common factors
        if (list[i] % l == 0 && list[j] % l == 0) { //if these two values have common factor
          count--;                 //the possible number of pair reduce by 1
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //  printf("%d\n count",count);
  double PI = sqrt(6.0000 * pair / count);
  return PI;
}
```

For this method it takes too long for the codecrunch to run and it mark me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try every value `[2...list[j])`, perhaps look for the [Greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)

Example `int gcd(int a, int b)` [Arjun Sreedharan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22281682/2410359) or [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37147041/2410359)

```
#if 0
  for (l = 2; l < list[j]; l++) {           //check for common factors
    ...
  }
#else
  if (gcd(list[i], list[j]) <= 1) count--;
#endif
```

---

Simplification possible as only the first factor > 1 needs to be found.